# Can you move Healing Spirit's AOE (and other aoe spells) through walls if you can see both points?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

For the spell "Healing Spirit," it says the following:

> As a bonus action on your turn, you can move the Spirit up to 30 feet to a space you can see.

Can you move the "The Intangible spirit" through a wall if you can see the start and end points?

Comment: For my example, what if you are standing at the end of a wall when you use your bonus action?  

    A..|..B
    ...|...
    ...|...
    ...P... Where P is the player and A&B are the two points

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take the [tour] when you get the chance. It's important to remember that there are thousands of RPGs out there; can you tell us which game & edition you're asking about?

Comment: Please state which game and edition you are asking about, since it was buried in @ObliviousSage's comment

Comment: I’ve added the [dnd-5e] since the quoted text matches the description of the 5e spell *healing spirit*.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes, it is incorporeal

It is described as an intangible spirit. So I would say yes. Further supported by the fact that you can physically occupy its space it is incorporeal in order to heal.

The only argument I can think of someone using is IF the spirit moves from Point 1 to Point 2 in a line (instead of disappearing from Point 1 and reappearing at Point 2), then technically you don't see it while it is inside the wall. But I don't see that argument really holding up, as you wouldn't see the spirit if it were in e.g. the Darkness spell, nor does the spell require you see the spirit before moving it. Most people would still say you could move it.

TLDR:
Yes, it is intangible/incorporeal. You fulfill the criteria of the spell which is use a Bonus Action to move to an area you can see. (Strictly speaking it does not require you to see the point you want to move it to, only see the place when you cast the spell and see the spirit when you want to heal someone.)

Comment: Welcome to the stack Nexhai, take the [tour] when you have a moment. You’ll notice that this question originally didn’t specify what game they were playing, and it is pretty important for us to know what game a question is about when answering. I’ve written some guidance for approaching questions like this: [What should I do when a question does not specify the game system being used?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11722/62294), give it a read when you have a few minutes.